# How do I make element keep hover ability but make clicks go through it?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a box which expands into four boxes (which are also links) when you hover over it. To do this I have 5 boxes. One which acts as the parent box and contains all others, one which expands on hover, and the other three which are in the second one positioned to opposite corners. My problem is that the second box has to be over the others for the hover to work but then the user can't click the buttons below it.

Here's an abbreviated version (CSS then HTML):

```
#sidebar {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  position: relative
}
#sidebar #container {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  transition: all 2s;
}
#sidebar #container:hover {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}
#sidebar #container #button1 {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}
/* Repeat with two buttons positioned to bottom corners */

<div id="sidebar">
  <div id="container">
    <div id="button1"></div>
    <!-- Repeat buttons again -->
  </div>
</div>
```

I'd rather not use anything but CSS and HTML, but if it's the only way I'll be open to it. [Jsfiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/4zLjas39/)

EDIT: I fixed the jsfiddle with idrumgood's solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's your negative z-index that's causing the issue. That places it behind everything else.

Comment: The negative z index is to place the buttons "behind" everything else so that they can't bee seen when the entire thing is compressed. Although I could probably put the sidebar in the container and put its z index just above everything else. *facepalms at missing such a simple solution*

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this style to your links:

```
a{
    display:inline-block;    
}
```

And adjust the size of the second link. Try it and tell me! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can add the hover effect to your sidebar instead and changing the visibility of your buttons,as well as removing z-indexes http://jsfiddle.net/4zLjas39/12/

```
#container a div{visibility:hidden;}
#sidebar:hover #container a div{visibility:visible;}
```

Comment: Not bad, but this creates an unpleasant "snap" when you move the mouse off of it rather than the smooth transition.

Answer (score -2):

You can allow clicks to pass through an element by setting it's css `pointer-events` to none

```
#the_invisible_object{
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

Comment: In general this is true, however it doesn't apply to the code in question.

Comment: I see, in this case, the pointer events are needed for the hover animation.